# C++ Can't input with keyboard

Tags: loops, c++11

If "password" is not inputted, the code asks for the name of the user. If the name is found, it assigns their first name as the User.

The code blow is a simplified version of a larger one but the problem is exactly the same. In the else if statement, `std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;` repeats itself infinitely. If I remove `std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;` I am incapable of inputting anything. It's as if my keyboard was unplugged. Tried using goto, cases, and even making a function out of it, yet the problem persists. Any ideas?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
std::string User;
std::string text;
std::string PassWord;
std::cin >> PassWord;
    if(PassWord == "password")
    {
        User = "Ryan";
    }
    else if (PassWord != "password")
    {
        std::string line;
        std::string LastName;
        std::string FirstName;
        std::string AttemptUser;
        std::ifstream NameFile;
        int offset; 

        std::cout << "Name?" << std::endl; 
        NameFile.open("C:\\Filepath\\Names.txt");

        if(NameFile.is_open())
        {
            while(!NameFile.eof())
            {
                while(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName)//<---Needing to press Ctrl-z still a problem!
                AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
                if((offset = line.find(AttemptUser, 0)) != std::string::npos) 
                {
                    NameFile.close();
                    std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;
                    User = FirstName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    do
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, text);
        if(text.find("the code") != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << "Yes " << User << ", this is the code" << std::endl;
        }
    }
while (text != "close");
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through to see what happens? Have you asked your professor? And `goto` is evil. Also, you're never actually reading the file, just opening and closing it.

Comment: Have VS 2012 Express so can't step through. Please elaborate on how I'm not actually reading the file. Might be my problem.

Comment: You refer to `NameFile` (btw, stop capitalizing the first character in local variables - not good practice) on exactly 4 lines. the declaration, `if(NameFile.is_open())`, `while(!NameFile.eof())`, and `NameFile.close()`. At no point do you actually read data from the file, so `.eof()` will *always* be false if the file exists and is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are several problems here, but SO is all about learning and fixing, so:

**Problem zero**
Put a

```
using namespace std;
```

before `main`, and stop putting `std::` in front of everything in the `std::` namespace. Not a functional difference, but you should probably know what that means at this point.

**Problem, the first:**

```
         while(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName)//<---Needing to press Ctrl-z still a problem!
            AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
```

This will repeat forever unless you force quit the program (ctrl+c, ctrl+z, etc.)You might have meant to include a curly brace after the `while(...)`.  Regardless of what follows, these two lines form a complete block, which means that the line

```
AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
```

Will be executed over and over until the condition

```
std:cin >> FirstName >> LastName;
```

evaluates to `false`, which will not happen. Look at `cin` in the C++ spec.

What you may have  *meant* to do is this:

```
         while(!(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName))//<---Needing to press Ctrl-z still a problem!
            AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
```

The difference is subtle, yet important. Also, using strings as a boolean operand is silly.

**Problem, the 2nd**

You never read the file. It's opened, checked for eof, and eventually (in theory, though it will never happen in this implementation) closed, but you never actually read anything from the file. Which means that `::eof` will **always** be false, assuming the file exists and is not empty.

**Problem, the 3rd**

```
if(PassWord == "password")
{
    ...
 }
else if (PassWord != "password")
{
    ....
}
```

Okay, this is like saying

```
if(I am alive)
{
    call me!
}
else if (I am not alive)
{
    send flowers or raid the closets;
}
```

Skip the `()` in the `else`. It's redundant, among (many) other things.

**Problem, the 4th**

The block

```
        while(!NameFile.eof())
        {
            while(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName)//<---Needing to press Ctrl-z still a problem!
            AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
            if((offset = line.find(AttemptUser, 0)) != std::string::npos) 
            {
                NameFile.close();
                std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;
                User = FirstName;
            }
        }
```

will utterly fail in an epic fashion if `offset` ever equals `line.find(AttemptUser,0)`, since you close the file, then check it for `eof` on the next loop, which will always happen unless you have figured out how to input *nothing* via the keyboard. Which can be difficult.

**Other**

If using visual studio, enter `Ctrl+A`, then `Ctrl+KD`. It should reformat your code (depending on your key bindings), and show you interesting things about your block/indentation structure that might surprise you.

**Guessing**

I'm going to go out on a limb, and say that this:

```
        while(!NameFile.eof())
        {
            while(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName)//<---Needing to press Ctrl-z still a problem!
            AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;
            if((offset = line.find(AttemptUser, 0)) != std::string::npos) 
            {
                NameFile.close();
                std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;
                User = FirstName;
            }
        }
```

should really be this:

```
std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName;

if (FirstName != "" || LastName != "")
{
    AttemptUser = FirstName + " " + LastName;
    while(!NameFile.eof())
    {
        getline(NameFile,line); //<< !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! READ THE FILE
        if (line.find(AttemptUser,0) != string::npos)
        {
            /// found
            cout << "Hello " << FirstName << endl;
            User = FirstName; /// I hope you don't have multiple users with the same first name.
            break; // <------- REALLY FREAKING IMPORTANT
        }
    }
    cout << "Who are you?\n";
}
```

I could keep going. Fix this stuff, realize that VS2012 Express does, actually, have a debugger, and come back with more questions.

Comment: Thank you! A lot to go over and learn. Not homework, just personal project. Through learning what I can online, a lot of parts I couldn't really grasp are explained here. **Also**, your comment in the last block of code says, "I hope you don't have multiple users with the same first name." That is expected. That is why the first name and last name are checked. If both are true in the same line, than only the first name of the line will be ID'd as User. Is that not the case with how things are set up?

Comment: You're checking both first and last for authentication, but only keeping the first name (stored in `User`) around for use later in your application. If you have two users - Steve J and Steve W - who have different permissions, or if you wanted to track their activity and tell who did what later on, you wouldn't be able to tell them apart. (Honestly, though, I wouldn't worry about it at this point.)

Answer (score 0):

`FirstName + LastName = AttemptUser;` is not doing what you are expecting.
It should be most likely be `AttemptUser = FirstName + ' ' + LastName;`.

It is stuck in a infite loop because `AttemptUser` is never given a value which leads me to say that you should always initialize your variables. Declaring variables without a value and then referencing them like you've done here can cause very unexpected results. Just learn the habit of always giving an initial value when you declare a variable and it will save you from a lot of trouble.

When you did `FirstName + LastName = AttemptUser;` you were actually assigining the value of `AttemptUser` to `LastName`.

**EDIT**
Had to do a little debugging... The variable `line` is never assigned. You are not properly reading the file or using its data anywhere. Use `std::getline(fstream, string)` to read the file line-by-line. Also the `while(std::cin >> FirstName >> LastName)` should be inverted as in "read again if user input is **in**valid".

Comment: Made the changes and after the name is in, 'std::cout << "Hello " << FirstName << std::endl;' doesn't even output at all. It also seems I'm still having issue with being able to use the keyboard. After I input the name, nothing goes on screen.